# Sweet alert Content moves on hover in ie11

Tags: internet-explorer-11, sweetalert2

[gif of what is happening](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TaB9A.gif)

The content of swal moves upward then down on hover,
the title is set equal to a whitespace

```
<h2 class="swal2-title" id="swal2-title" style="display: flex;"></h2>
```

[style in internet explorer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yL39b.png)

```js
swal.fire({
            title: ' ',
            text: sText,
            showCancelButton: true,
            showConfirmButton: true,
            confirmButtonText: i18n.t('["GENERAL"]["BUTTON.CONFIRM"][0]'),
            cancelButtonText: i18n.t('["GENERAL"]["BUTTON.CANCEL"][0]'),
            confirmButtonColor: '#fe792c',
            reverseButtons: true
        }
)
```

Comment: I suggest trying to provide a sample code to test the issue on our end. It can help us to understand the issue in better way. Only the GIF and the image of the CSS code is not much help to find the cause of the issue. Thanks for your understanding.

Comment: @Deepak-MSFT i edited the post.thank you

Comment: It can be possible that some CSS is causing this issue. It can be related to Flex. If you can post your CSS code along with your HTML that we can directly run in the IE browser then we can try to check for it. It can help to narrow down the issue.

Comment: instead of an empty space, I used '<br>' insted. that fixed the moving ui problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead of an empty space, I used '
' insted. that fixed the moving ui problem